# Best place to save user information for Windows XP and Vista applications

Tags: file, windows-vista, windows-xp, save

I need to save a user's login information in encrypted form for this application I'm building, but I'm not sure of the best place to save the file. I don't want to save it into the program application folder as I want it per user.

So what is the best folder (or way) to save it into?

Edit: Using C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data may be the appropriate place according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Folders). The article says this location is used for "User-specific and computer-specific application settings".

Edit: Cruizer pointed out in the comments (I'd reply there but I can't comment yet) that in Vista it is C:\Users\%username% and that it shouldn't be hard-coded. Thanks.

Comment: Vista doesn't have C:\Documents and Settings\%username% --> it's in C:\Users\%username% by default, and it can be changed so the path shouldn't be hard-coded

Comment: The proper way to get this folder is by calling:

SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, szPath, CSIDL_PERSONAL, false)

Comment: Ammendment to my comment.  You need to use CSIDL_APPDATA.  CSIDL_PERSONAL is for the users documents directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Data Protection API (DPAPI) - a part of the CryptoAPI in XP and Vista. Here's a good overview of DPAPI - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, local application path looks like a winner.

I found this article in MSDN to get it in C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx

Example:

```
char localAppPath[MAX_PATH];
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, localAppPath);
```

Comment: You should not store user credentials in a plain file, even if encrypted. You should really keep these in the Data Protection storage. But it's your choice after all... :-)

Answer (score 0):

are you using .NET? how about [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx)? That way you wouldn't have to worry about the directory location, it'll just be there...

Comment: You may need to take care that new versions/ installs of the application can still see your original isolated storage file.

Answer (score 0):

User information should always go in some sub directory in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% (Which maps to the users home directory). No exceptions.
A good place for application specific settings per user is a sub directory inside %APPDATA%. This maps to:  "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Application Data" on XP and to: " %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming" on Vista.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET to get special folders you can use

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

or

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

for the non-roaming version.