# WPF/C#: Where should I be saving user preferences files?

Tags: c#, wpf, file

What is the recommended location to save user preference files? Is there a recommended method for dealing with user preferences?

Currently I use the path returned from `typeof(MyLibrary).Assembly.Location` as a default location to store files generated or required by the application.

EDIT:
I found two related/interesting questions:

- [Best place to save user information for Windows XP and Vista applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147533/best-place-to-save-user-information-xp-and-vista)
- [What's the way to implement Save / Load functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348022/whats-the-way-to-implement-save-load-functionality)

EDIT #2:
This is just a note for people like me who had never used settings before.
Settings are pretty useful, but I had to do a whole bunch of digging to figure out what was going on (coming from the Python world, not something I am used too). Things got complicated as I wanted to save dictionaries and apparently they can't be serialized. Settings also seem to get stored in 3 different files depending on what you do. There is an `app.config`, `user.config` and a `settings.setting` file. So here are two more links that I found useful:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ddeaca86-a093-4997-82c9-01bc0c630138
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/efe370dc-f933-4e55-adf7-3cd8063949b0/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use the Application Settings easily enough.

If you haven't done so before just right click on the project and choose Properties.  Select the Settings tab.  Make sure you chose "User" for the scope (otherwise the setting is read-only).

The code to access this is simple:

```
forms.Width = Application1.Properties.Settings.Default.Width;
```

If you need to save it:

```
Application1.Properties.Settings.Default.Width = forms.Width;
Application1.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

In the sample above, Width is the custom setting name you define in the Settings tab and Application1 is the Namespace of your application.

**Edit: Responding to further questions**

You mentioned you wanted to store Dictionary objects in the Settings.  As you discovered, you can't do this directly because Dictionary objects are not serializable.  However, you can create your own serializable dictionary pretty easily.  Paul Welzer had an excellent example [on his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx).

You have a couple of links which sort of muddy the situation a little. Your original question is where to save "User Preference Files".  I'm pretty certain Microsoft's intention with the Settings functionality is exactly that... storing user skin preferences, layout choices, etc. It not meant as a generic repository for an application's data although it could be easily abused that way.

The data is stored in separate places for a good reason. Some of the settings are Application settings and are read-only. These are settings which the app needs to function but is not specific to a user (for example, URIs to app resources or maybe a tax rate).  These are stored in the app.config.

User settings are stored in an obfuscated directory deep within the User Document/Settings folder.  The defaults are stored in app.config (I think, can't recall for certain off the top of my head) but any user changes are stored in their personal folder. This is meant for data that changes from user to user. (By "user" I mean Windows user, not your app's user.)

Hope this clarified this somewhat for you. The system is actually pretty simple. It might seem a little foreign at first but after a few days of using it you'll never have to think of it again... it just works.

Comment: when you say access code is: forms.Width = Application1.Properties.Settings.Default.Width; Does this mean it loads Width that was possibly saved in a previous session?

Comment: Yes, the little sample he provided will restore the previous width. If you're going to use it (along with height and position), make sure you have some checks to ensure the window is visible.
Restoring the position is a bad feature for dual monitor users when they remove the second one.

Comment: Yes... this sample was just the first thing that popped into my head.  You can store almost anything in the settings, including arrays. I have a rather extreme app that stores a large deserialized List of objects.

Comment: What if you are saving dynamic settings? For example, if I an keeping track of screens that a user has open and their positions, these settings are dynamic. Does this require a different scenario?

Comment: @Josh - No, you can do it the same way.  It might not be the most efficient way for you but it will still work.

Comment: Did some research on that this morning. It looks like you can specify any object as a setting as long as it is TypeConvertable to/from string or XmlSerializable. The strange thing is that VS never lists any of your custom types as available in the settings pane, so you have to type in the complete namespace/type path. Works great though!

Answer (score 28):

When running as non-admin or on Vista you can't write to the "Program files" folder (or any sub folder of it).

The correct location to store user preference is (replace MyCompanyName and MyApplicationName with the correct names, obviously)

On disk:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\MyCompanyName\\MyApplicationName"
```

Or in the registry under the key:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyCompanyName\MyApplicationName
```

Those location are per-user and they work with non-admin user, several users using the same computer, fast user switching, terminal services and all the other ways people can interact with your software.

If you need a common location for all users then:

1. It will only work when the user run as an administrator
2. It will not work reliably on Vista
3. You have to take care of everything yourself (like two users running the application on the same computer at the same time via fast user switching).

and the locations are:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationCommonData) + "\\MyCompanyName\\MyApplicationName"
```

Or in the registry under the key:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MyCompanyName\MyApplicationName
```

Comment: Thanks Nir. Your first alternative sounds like what I am looking for.

Comment: I think your second one should be CommonApplicationData, not ApplicationCommonData.

Comment: "you can't write to the "Program files"" - you must not write there ever even if you have admin privileges.

Answer (score 3):

You can use isolated storage. You can isolate by user, assembly and/or domain.

Introduction to Isolated Storage
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(VS.80).aspx

Types of Isolation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh5d60e1(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

the following seems to be the best option:

```
Application.UserAppDataPath
```

Comment: This is not available in WPF, maybe in WinForms only?

Comment: Correct, so sorry, the answer gets -1 because this is a `WinForms` only answer and the title of the question specifically asks for `WPF`.