# How to store app settings?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, app-config

I am doing a wpf application and I use application settings in app.config file:

```
var datapath = Properties.Settings.Default.DataSource;
```

...

How to make application to load the app.config file, if it present from the same location where exe file run from., so user can change app.config and run it with new settings. By default app.config ignored and application uses always default settings

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396229/wpf-c-where-should-i-be-saving-user-preferences-files).

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF/C#: Where should I be saving user preferences files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396229/wpf-c-where-should-i-be-saving-user-preferences-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save and restore any settings using Binding in TwoWay mode. TwoWay needed for auto storing changes of property. For example binding height of the window:

```
Height="{Binding Source={x:Static self:Properties.Settings.Default}, 
                         Path=ApplicationHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

To make binding works you need to create setting record in project properties (with name ApplicationHeight in example). To save setting on app closing use:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

in Window.Closed or Application.Exit events.

Comment: Please consider summarizing the link in your answer. If the link dies, so does your answer.

Comment: Have posted full answer with link to source.

Comment: Actually the question is - how user can customize the application using app.config without rebuild, but not how application save it's settings itself